# How to solve ArraysList sort error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sorting

So I'm trying to sort my music alphabetically but nothing seems to be working, then from another question I was told to use this code to sort my content -

```
Collections.sort(songsList, new Comparator<File>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });
```

So I added this to my function like this -

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
            File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(songsList, new Comparator<File>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });
        // return songs list array      
        return songsList;
    }
```

Then I got this error

```
The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>, new 
 Comparator<File>(){})
```

So after some research I figure I had to change `Collections.sort` to `Arrays.sort`but still no luck.

If you could help me on how to fix this itll be great.

Full Class -

```
package com.ascendapps.nexplay;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.os.Environment;

public class SongsManager {
    final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath() + "/";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager() {

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files and store the details in
     * ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
            File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(songsList, new Comparator<File>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });
        // return songs list array      
        return songsList;
    }

    private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
        if (directory != null) {
            File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void addSongToList(File song) {
        if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) {
            HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            songMap.put("songTitle",
                    song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
            songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(songMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Comparator` is comparing `File`s, you are comparing `String`s, hence passing an invalid generic type, which won't compile.

You may not even need a `Comparator` passed to your `sort` method in this case, if you're using the default `String` lexicographic comparison.

If your `songList` variable is an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` however, you would need to use a `Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>`, which to me sounds like a potential design issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'll keep that in mind, One more thing though as I haven't quite fully understood it. How am I to fix this error? Is there another way I could sort my content?

Comment: @SmallVille you're welcome. To solve your error, use a `Comparator` of the type you are comparing (right now that would be a `HashMap<string, String>` I think), or the default `Comparator` (no `Comparator` argument). Bottom line, you probably don't want to compare `Map` in their natural order, so you might want to resolve to custom `Object`s and override `toString`, but it's really hard to tell with the code you posted and might pertain to a different scope than your current question's.

Comment: I have posted my full class, if you wouldn't mind taking a look and seeing if you could help me solve this as I'm having a bit of trouble doing so. changing Comparator<File> to HashMap<String, String> causes lots of errors.

Comment: @SmallVille as said, I'd advise you to use a custom `Object` (say, a `Song` with a `title` and a `path` properties) instead of your `HashMap`, and override its `toString` method by returning the title, which is what i suppose you want to order your songs with. You can then dispense of the `Comparator` implementation entirely and sort by using default `Comparator`. That implies a few changes in your design but ultimately it might simplify your life.